# Commit on Pull Request of Remote Fork

Tags: git, github

Someone recently forked a repository I am an owner of, created a feature branch, pushed several commits, and created a pull request to merge his forked branch into `master` — a typical git workflow.

Is there a way that I can commit on his PR feature branch? I like the PR he created, but I want to make a few changes before I merge it into `master`.

This seems like an elementary question, but I can't find the documentation for this anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to perform the merge locally, rather than via the GitHub web ui.

Follow [these instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/) to check out the pull request locally, and then you can `git merge` it into any branch you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just checkout his branch. Do you changes in that code. Commit your code in that branch.

That pull request will automatically update with your changes. Now you should be able to merge that code.

Comment: I don't think I'd be able to push code to his forked repo / branch, right? It's his fork, so he owns all right / push access to it, I think.

Comment: I think you should be able to checkout his branch and then push your commit in the same branch. Access restrictions are decided on the repository level not the branch level.

Comment: Even If you don't want to push your code in his branch. You can create a new fork from his branch and then after doing your commits, you can merge your new branch with your base branch.